# Hibernate Search @IndexedEmbedded

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a similar situation like [this one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-mapping.html#search-mapping-associated)

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Place {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @DocumentId
    private Long id;

    @Field( index = Index.TOKENIZED )
    private String name;

    @OneToOne( cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE } )
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Address address;
    ....
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Field(index=Index.TOKENIZED)
    private String street;

    @Field(index=Index.TOKENIZED)
    private String city;

    @ContainedIn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="address")
    private Set<Place> places;
    ...
}
```

The problem now is the following:
If I change for example the *name* field in entity *Place* which entities are going to be re-indexed?

1) Only the *name* field?

2) The whole *Place* entity?

3) The whole *Place* entity and the entities annotated with *@IndexedEmbedded*?

The one I need for my purpose would be the third. So if it is not standard, could there be any solution to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately it's really the third, so I was lucky and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to re-index the Place Entity manually

```
public void updateIndex(T entity){
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
        fullTextEntityManager.index(entity);
        fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().optimize(entity.getClass());
    }
```

Secondly if you are using hibernate you can configure lucene in `persistence.xml` to automatically update the indexes of the entities that are changed

Comment: Actually that's not what I'm lookin for. I was interested in the automatic process

Comment: Can you give an example of this configuration?